# How to find JsonParse exception in json

Tags: json, parsing, objectmapper

I am trying to parse below json. This has to throw me the error saying incorrect json format. But the parsor parses the json only till "value:15" and is not throwing any exception. How can I achieve this?

```
String json = { and : [{key: domain, value: cricket}, {key : STAT_CDE,value : 15}]}, { and : [{key: domain, value: football}, {key : STAT_CDE,value : 10}]}
```

Sample Code I am using:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readTree(json); //this line is not throwing me any exception
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonTestParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"and\" : [{\"key\": \"domain\", \"op\": \"=\", \"value\": \"cricket\"}, {\"key\" : \"STAT_CDE\",\"op\" : \"=\",\"value\" : \"13\"}]},"+
                "{ \"and\" : [{\"key\": \"domain\", \"op\": \"=\", \"value\": \"Football\"}, {\"key\" : \"STAT_CDE\",\"op\" : \"=\",\"value\" : \"10\"}]}";

        System.out.println("json: " + json);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            mapper.readTree(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("object mapper exp");

        }
        System.out.println("mapper complete");

    }

}
```

And the output:

line 1: json: { "and" : [{"key": "domain", "op": "=", "value": "cricket"}, {"key" : "STAT_CDE","op" : "=","value" : "13"}]},{ "and" : [{"key": "domain", "op": "=", "value": "Football"}, {"key" : "STAT_CDE","op" : "=","value" : "10"}]}
line 2: mapper complete

Comment: That's not JSON, JSON is a string, and you should double quote property names

Comment: okay. Here is the java json string that I use: { \"and\" : [{\"key\": \"domain\", \"op\": \"=\", \"value\": \"cricket\"}, {\"key\" : \"STAT_CDE\",\"op\" : \"=\",\"value\" : \"15\"}]},{ \"and\" : [{\"key\": \"domain\", \"op\": \"=\", \"value\": \"football\"}, {\"key\" : \"STAT_CDE\",\"op\" : \"=\",\"value\" : \"10\"}]}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there is no problem with that json format! Syntactically, you're assigning a comma-delimited list to `json`, which is perfectly valid code - it will set `json` to the first item in the list and not do anything with the rest of the values.

After your code executes, `json` looks like this:

```
String json = { and : [{key: domain, value: cricket}, {key : STAT_CDE,value : 15}]}
```

And this value has been ignored entirely:

```
{ and : [{key: domain, value: football}, {key : STAT_CDE,value : 10}]}
```

As you can see, `json` is structured perfectly well.

Also, it looks like you're expecting a `String` object, but you're supplying a map instead.

Try the following:

```
String json = "{ and : [{key: domain, value: cricket}, {key : STAT_CDE,value : 15}]}, { and : [{key: domain, value: football}, {key : STAT_CDE,value : 10}]}"
```

And then parse `json`. This will most certainly fail because the keys are not enclosed with double quotes (the `"` character), which is a requirement of json format.

## EDIT

To keep up to date with the question:

Here is a formatted view of the json you say you're working with:

```
{ 
    "and" : [
        {"key": "domain", "op": "=", "value": "cricket"}, 
        {"key" : "STAT_CDE","op" : "=","value" : "15"}
    ]
},
{
    "and" : [
        {"key": "domain", "op": "=", "value": "football"},
        {"key" : "STAT_CDE","op" : "=","value" : "10"}
    ]
}
```

The issue is that this is not a json object - it is TWO SEPARATE json objects, each of which is well-formed. I am guessing that `ObjectMapper` parses a full json structure, and ignores any trailing data without throwing an error.

If you'd like to capture the entire structure in json you will need to enclose them together, likely using an array:

```
[
    { 
        "and" : [
            {"key": "domain", "op": "=", "value": "cricket"}, 
            {"key" : "STAT_CDE","op" : "=","value" : "15"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "and" : [
            {"key": "domain", "op": "=", "value": "football"},
            {"key" : "STAT_CDE","op" : "=","value" : "10"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Sorry for sharing the edited string.  Here is the entire string that I supply to the String. ObjectMapper is still not throwing the exception. I validated this online and I see error. The string is      "{ \"and\" : [{\"key\": \"domain\", \"op\": \"=\", \"value\": \"cricket\"}, {\"key\" : \"STAT_CDE\",\"op\" : \"=\",\"value\" : \"15\"}]},{ \"and\" : [{\"key\": \"domain\", \"op\": \"=\", \"value\": \"football\"}, {\"key\" : \"STAT_CDE\",\"op\" : \"=\",\"value\" : \"10\"}]}"